# How do I change what loot a Zombie drops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to change loot on Zombie with a command:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Zombie] {Equipment:[{},{},{id:arrow,Count:1b},{id:fish,Count:1b},{}],DropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.0F,0.0F,2.000F]}
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Minecraft 1.11?

Comment: yes im using 1.11

Comment: @OnePvP if you want to change loot from ALL zombies, look into changing Loot tables (http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Loot_table )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobs now have `ArmorItems` (and a separate `HandItems`) rather than just `Equipment`.

`DropChances` has also been split correspondingly into `ArmorDropChances` and `HandDropChances`.

Your command should thus look something like:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Zombie] {ArmorItems:[{},{id:arrow,Count:1b},{id:fish,Count:1b},{}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.0F,0.0F,2.00F]}
```